# How to autowire NamedParameterJdbcTemplate in Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, named-parameters

I understand that Spring Boot automatically configure JDBCTemplate for us. But i don't know exactly which way is correct when i want to autowire NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.

```
private NamedParameterJdbcTemplate template
```

or

```
private NamedParameterJdbcTemplate namedParameterJdbcTemplate;
```

P.S : i'm using Spring Boot 1.5.1 Release

Answer (score 1):

I just found the answer by reading Spring Boot API, both ways are working and it does not depend on what we name it. Problem was solved.